# react navigation custom tabBarComponent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

the navigationOptions code like that.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation})=>({
        tabBarLabel:'查看',
        headerTitle:navigation.state.params.title,
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor,focused }) => (
            <Image style={SKIN.tabImage} source={focused?AppImages.MyPost.lookchoose:AppImages.MyPost.look}/>
        ),
    });
```

this is my Tab componet,how I can get tabBarLabel and tabBarIcon?

```
export default class Tab extends Component {
    renderItem = (route, index) => {
        const {
            navigation,
            jumpToIndex,
        } = this.props;

        const focused = index === navigation.state.index;
        const color = focused ? this.props.activeTintColor : this.props.inactiveTintColor;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                style={styles.tabItem}
                onPress={() => jumpToIndex(index)}
            >
                <View
                    style={styles.tabItem}>
                    {this.props.renderIcon(color,focused)}
                    <Text style={{ color }}>{this.props.getLabel()}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };

    render(){
        console.log('Tab this.props',this.props);
        const {navigation,} = this.props;

        const {routes,} = navigation.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.tab}>
                {routes && routes.map(this.renderItem)}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I custom Tab,now I want use that but some bug show me.
like that,
[imagebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH8yP.png)
please help me...

Answer (score 0):

try updating the render method with this code:

```
 render(){
            console.log('Tab this.props',this.props);
            const {navigation,} = this.props;

            const {routes,} = navigation.state;
            return (
                <View style={styles.tab}>
                    //pass down the route and the index to the renderItem function
                    {routes && routes.map((route,index) => this.renderItem(route, index) )}
                </View>
            );
```

Comment: renderIcon and getLabel do you know how to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
  renderItem = (route, index) => {
        const {
            navigation,
            jumpToIndex,
        } = this.props;

        const focused = index === navigation.state.index;
        const color = focused ? this.props.activeTintColor : this.props.inactiveTintColor;
        let TabScene = {
            focused:focused,
            route:route,
            tintColor:color
        };
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={route.key}
                style={styles.tabItem}
                onPress={() => jumpToIndex(index)}
            >
                <View
                    style={styles.tabItem}>
                    {this.props.renderIcon(TabScene)}
                    <Text style={{ color }}>{this.props.getLabel(TabScene)}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };
```